# find the class in debug

Tags: java, debugging, class, screen

I'm writing Java in eclipse and I'm just wondering if there's a shortcut or a way to open the class of the screen you are looking at when debugging an application.

So, I'm debugging a very large application, and at some point I open a dialog within the application, and I want to know which class in the Java project contains the code responsible for this dialog. Is there a shortcut to open this class in eclipse?

Comment: Hit Ctrl, keep it pressed and click on class name.

Comment: Instead of `ctrl+click` you can stand on the specific method/class and press `F3`

Comment: @ftom2 He's trying to find out what the class name is.

Comment: He wants to know what class contains the method he is just standing on, `F3` will take him there

Comment: @ftom2 I don't think that's what he means. If that was his problem, he could just scroll up until he found the `class` keyword. @Jonathan Viccary, will you please clarify?

Comment: @S.L.Barth - and what if this method is in another object? he wants a quick way of getting to the defining class.

Comment: @ftom2 Er... how would a Java method be defined in a another object than the class that contains it? Do you mean via inheritance? I don't think that's what the OP means.

Comment: Ok, to clarify. I run the application in debug mode, I go through a process of using the application and eventually I arrive at a dialog which pops up within the application. I think to myself: "I would like to know which class in the source code is responsible for generating the popup for this dialog", or even if the screen I'm on in the application is just a general screen class and not a dialog...is there a way to open the class in eclipse (without knowing what class it is) from the looking at the screen/dialog in the application?

Comment: @S.L.Barth - are you familiar with the term 'Object Instance', this instance can have methods and you can use it in other classes. Jonathan Viccary - I don't think there is a way to do that just by looking at the dialog window.

Comment: @ftom2 I'm googling for "Object Instance", but all I've found so far is about instantiating objects. You are referring to something more complicated than calling methods on a different class, right?

Comment: No, i'm referring exactly to that, you instantiate an object and use it's methods in another class, no need for inheritance. You are in class A that calls a method of an instance of class B and you want to see the method in B, so you can open B and look for the method, or you can press `F3` and get to it instantly, but that is really off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you just want to go to a specific implementation of method or a class, ctrl + click will take you to the code (if it is not third party code, you will be able to see it)
2. If you are asking how to see the code getting executed in debug mode, use F6 key instead of F8.

Comment: Ok, to clarify. I run the application in debug mode, I go through a process of using the application and eventually I arrive at a dialog which pops up within the application. I think to myself: "I would like to know which class in the source code is responsible for generating the popup for this dialog", or even if the screen I'm on in the application is just a general screen class and not a dialog...is there a way to open the class in eclipse (without knowing what class it is) from the looking at the screen/dialog in the application?

Comment: It seems that you are given a running code base, which you have not actually worked on. If I was in that position, rather than looking for the class straightforward, I will backtrack from dialogue box. A simple way will be to search for the contents of dialogue box in the codebase. In eclipse it is pretty simple, go to search, chose file search and provide the contents. It will show you from where exactly the dialogue box is getting generated (A Javascript/ JSP/ HTML or directly from Java class). That will be a good starting point.

Comment: Yeh, well thats the obvious, long-winded way to do it. I can make some custom shortcut, I was just wondering if there was an existing shortcut...?